# laravel 4 ORM query operators

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a weird issue-- my `Tasks` table has a `due_at` column. I seeded the table with 50 values in the future, then in my admin controller I want to grab those tasks to show in the admin panel:

```
// AdminController.php
$tasks = Task::where('due_at', '>=', 'NOW()')->get();
dd($tasks); // shows zero results
```

Running the same query in phpmyadmin results in the expected 50 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE due_at >= now(); // returns 50 rows
```

If I just reverse the operator, it returns 50 results:

```
// AdminController.php
$tasks = Task::where('due_at', '<=', 'NOW()')->get();
dd($tasks); // shows 50 results
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Might be a problem with Eloquent. does `Task::whereRaw('due_at >= NOW()')->get()` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do this:

```
$tasks = Task::where('due_at', '<=', DB::raw('NOW()'))->get();
```

Turn on query logging in your MySQL server and I think you will find that the Laravel 4 query builder is interpreting your string 'NOW()' into something you don't expect.  You have to wrap that in DB::raw() to get the raw string into the query.